# Wordpress to return post preview submitted

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a user content driven wordpress site. I need the user's post to preview its contents before the page/post redirects. So, once the form is submitted, instead of a "thank you for posting" message I need the form to first return a preview of the submission. This is just so the user can see what the contents would look like.

I am relatively new to Wordpress and coding PHP. Please forgive me if I seem rather dumb. Here is the code I am battling with:

```
            <div id="site-content-column" class="users-posts-section"><?php

    if(isset($_GET['complete'])){ ?>

                <div class="page-body">
                    <div class="page-body">
                        <?php get_post (); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

        <?php 
    }else{

        post_thumbnail(); 

        if(have_posts()){ 

            while(have_posts()){ 

                the_post(); ?>
                <div class="page-body">
                    <h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                    <div class="page-text">
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div><?php
            }
        } ?>
```

Your assistance would be very much appreciated.

Thank you,